# The Use of \addcontentsline{toc} Seems to Augment the Vertical Space Between Minipage Outputs

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, minipage, vertical-spacing

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[lf]{electrum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}
\end{minipage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}}

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{\color{red}{Text without addcontentsline{toc}.}}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{Why?}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

The code contains three minipages (each containing one of the three displayed lines) with a 20pt vertical spaces added between them.

In addition, the first minipage has the line of code `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}}` immediately after it. I would not expect that this would affect the spacing between the first and second displayed statements---but apparently, it does---as is evident in the output.

**UPDATE** I have noticed that if I comment-out `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}}`, the space between the first two minipage outputs is decreased---but is still larger than the space between the 2nd and 3rd outputs:

[image]

Remark: In the MWE, I do not actually produce a table of contents, as it does not seem necessary for the question I pose:

QUESTION: (i) What is causing the added space between the first two outputs when `\addcontentsline{toc}` is commented out? (ii) Why should the use of `\addcontentsline{toc}` cause the said extra space to be increased? (iii) How may I have the spacing between the three outputs be the same? (NOTE: An answer has been posted which suggests the use of `\offinterlineskip`---which seems to work fine for this MWE; however, if the minipage outputs are enlarged to more than one line, the spacing between the displayed lines within the minipage seems to be reduced to 0pt from the original amount.)

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `\bf` which was superseded by `\bfseries` nearly 30 years ago?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The `\addcontentsline` will not introduce spurious spaces. Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[lf]{electrum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}
\end{minipage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}}
\rule{1pt}{20pt}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{\color{red}{Text without addcontentsline{toc}.}}
\end{minipage}
\rule{1pt}{20pt}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{Why?}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\centering
\offinterlineskip
\LARGE
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}
\end{minipage}}\par
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{\color{red}{Text without addcontentsline{toc}.}}
\end{minipage}}\par
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{Why?}%
\end{minipage}}\par

\vskip20pt
\begin{center}
\offinterlineskip
\LARGE
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}
\end{minipage}}\par
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}}
\vskip20pt
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{\color{red}{Text without addcontentsline{toc}.}}
\end{minipage}}\par
\vskip20pt
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{Why?}%
\end{minipage}}\par
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer; it seems to work fine for the single line outputs of the MWE. However, when an output is enlarged to say, a multi-line paragraph, the use of `\offinterlineskip` seems to reduce the original spacing between the lines (within the minipage) to 0pt. Do you know of a way to override this?

Comment: @mlchristians  You can safely remove it. I just introduced it to show how to totally control the vertical spacing. You have to tell TeX to start a paragraph and end a paragraph. That what the `fbox` does. You can also remove them and put `par\leavemode` and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

The toc issue is a red herring here.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
A1

\vspace{20pt}

B1

\vspace{20pt}

C1
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}

A2

\vspace{20pt}

B2

\vspace{20pt}

C2

\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Which yields

[image]

B1 is Closer to C1 than B2 to C2.

Minipages are just like one big single letter. And as for the single letters it depends on the exact spacing vs the other commands. Try it with your MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[lf]{electrum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}

%added a line space here

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
Text
\end{minipage}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}}

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
Text
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
Text
\end{minipage}%

%added a line space here

\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Yields

[image]

Versus

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[lf]{electrum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
Text
\end{minipage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\bf Text with addcontentsline{toc}.}}

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
Text
\end{minipage}

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
Text
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Yields

[image]